# Adding a | to the nav bar

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

I've seen some posts but, I can't figure it out on my specific lines of code. Can anyone help me add a | between 'About Us' and 'Login' I'm just trying to separate them using a '|'and I'm not exactly sure how to tweak my code to make that happen?

HTML

```
color:rgba(152,226,80,0.6); font-family: 'Bahnschrift Regular';" title="This Header is rendered by /app/_layout/site-header/site-header.component.html">
   <div id="logo">
     <a href="/index.html">
     </a>
 </div>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarsExampleDefault">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/" style="color:White;" >Home</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">            
            <div class="dropdown">
           <li class="dropbtn">Services</li>
           <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="/carmaintenance" style="text-align:center">Car Maintenance
              ______________________
            </a>
            <a href="/gogreenseminars" style="text-align:center">Go Green Seminars
              ______________________
            </a>
            <a href="/microgridresources" style="text-align:center">Microgrid Resources
              ______________________
            </a>
            <a href="/gardeningtogether" style="text-align:center">Gardening Together
              ______________________
            </a>
            <a href="/volunteering" style="text-align:center">Volunteering and Activism
              ______________________
            </a>
            <a href="/recyclingefforts" style="text-align:center">Recycling Efforts
              ______________________
            </a>            
            <a href="/inhousevegancafe" style="text-align:center;">In-House Vegan Cafe              
            </a>    

            </div>
            </div>            
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/dashboard"style="color:White;">Membership Plans</a>
          </li>          
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about" style="color:White;">About Us</a>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login"style="color:White">Login</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
```

CSS

```
/* Position the navbar container inside the image */
/*.container {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 20px;
  width: auto;
  top:3%;
  left:1%;
}
*/

/* The navbar */
.topnav {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: rgba(152,226,80,0.6);

}

/* Navbar links */
.topnav a {
  float: right;
  color: #f2f2f2;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 16px;


}
.nav-link 
{
  /*background-color:;*/
  font-weight: bolder;
  color: white;  
  font-size: 125%;
  align-items:center;
  text-align:center;
  float: left;
  display: block;   
  margin-left: 65px;
  margin-right:5px;

}        
.navbar {
  float: left;
  width:66%;
  height:8%;
  opacity:1;
  border-radius:15px 0px 0px 15px;
  padding-left: 0%;
  top:3%;
  left:1%;  

}

.topnav a:hover {
  background-color: #ddd;
  color: black;  
}
/* Dropdown Button */
.dropbtn {
  background-color: rgba(152,226,80,0.0);
  color: white;
  padding: 8px;
  font-size: 125%;
  border: none;
  font-weight:bolder;
  margin-left:65px;
  margin-right:5px;
}

/* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;  
}

/* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute; 
  min-width: 90px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px rgba(152,226,80,0.0);
  z-index: 1; 
  text-align:center;
  padding-left:20px;
  padding-top:13px;
}

/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  background-color : rgba(152,226,80,0.6);
  font-weight:bolder;
  margin-top: -10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
//.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
//.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'Bahnschrift Regular';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight:bolder;
    src: local('Bahnschrift Regular'), url('BAHNSCHRIFT 1.woff') format('woff');
}
```

Any help would be nice and thank you in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bootstrap 4 add vertical devider pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50960837/bootstrap-4-add-vertical-devider-pipe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with either a border-left on the last li using :last-child a pseudo-element or a placed content using the :before pseduo-element. Note that by adding pseudo-elements - they are added as the first-child of the selected element. That may play a role in other styling issues.

**EDIT - following my comment above - the only valid child of a ul is an li so you should amend your HTMLstructure to ensure that any divs / dropdowns etc are children of an li - not of the parent ul.**

Thank you to @dale landry for the code skeleton used below :)

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
}

li, .nav-item {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 2px 12px;
  color:black;
}


.nav-item:last-child {
  border-left: solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="flex-box">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/services">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

or by using a :before pseudo element

```
.nav-item:last-child {
  position: relative
}
.nav-item:last-child:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "|";
  left: 0;
  color: #d4d4d4;
}
```

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
}

li, .nav-item {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 2px 12px;
  color:black;
  position: relative
}

.nav-item:last-child:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "|";
  left: 0;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="flex-box">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
       <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/services">Services</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about">About Us</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

or by simply adding aen element that is the same height as the entire li as a divider:

```
.nav-item:last-child {
  position: relative
}
.nav-item:last-child:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top:0;
  bottom:0; 
  width: 1px
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
}
```

And if you don't want to rely on the :last-child pseudo-selector - you can achieve the same by adding a class to the last item

```
      <li class="nav-item login-link">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login"style="color:White">Login</a>
      </li>

      //css
      .login-link {
         border-left: solid 1px #d4d4d4;
      }
```

And if you want the divider between every li - but not to the right of the last one then you can use the direct sibling combinator "+"

```
.nav-item + .nav-item {
  border-left: solid 1px #d4d4d4;
}
```

or by using a :before pseudo element

```
.nav-item {
  position: relative
}
.nav-item + .nav-item:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "|";
  left: 0;
  color: #d4d4d4;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this extensive answer. This has been extremely helpful!

Comment: Happy to have helped. If this resolves your issue - please mark the answer as "accepted" so that other devs know that this issue has been resolved. Happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

Simply wrap a bar in a list item tag in line with your nav at the spot you wish to have one. See my snipit. Now it is  `semantically valid code`

```css
.flex-box {
  display: flex;
}

li,
.nav-item {
  text-decoration: none;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 2px 4px;
  color: black;
}

.bar {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="flex-box">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
      <li class="dropbtn">Services</li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about">About Us</a>
      </li>
      <li class="bar">|</li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/login">Login</a>
      </li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

Comment: @gavgrif changed the markup to correct valid HTML... Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you add span in your li element of About us like following:

```
<li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" routerLink="/about" style="color:White;">About Us</a>
<span>|</span>
          </li>
```

Comment: adding a span to house the divider between other li's is semntaically correct - but not the most efficient approach. this will then affect the spacing between adjacent li's